# Safari does not change focus to the web page after address bar search

Tags: safari, search, web-browser

After completing a search in Safari (tested on version 13.1.2 and 14.0 with Catalina 10.15.6), the *address bar* remains in focus after pressing `return`. With other major browsers (including Chrome, Firefox, and Edge) the *web page* comes to focus after pressing `return`.

Safari not changing focus from the *address bar* to the *web page* is problematic for example when using DuckDuckGo as the default search engine. DDG allows navigation with `j` and `k`. The navigation requires the *web page* to be in focus and not the *address bar*.

Switching the focus from the *address bar* to the *web page* seems to require an extra step in Safari (such as pressing `esc` or clicking the web page) compared to other major browsers that switch to the *web page* automatically after pressing `return`. Is there a way to change the behavior in Safari to automatically switch focus to the *web page* after pressing `return`?

[image: Clicking on the web page or pressing esc is necessary to begin keyboard navigation]

[image: Safari General Settings]

[image: Safari Search Settings]

[image: Safari Advanced Settings]

I have removed extensions and tried various settings.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. This is not the behavior I see with Safari 13.1.2 on Catalina 10.15.6. Which macOS version are you on?

Comment: Thanks. I am also using Catalina 10.15.6. The behavior I described occurs for me with and without extensions enabled.

Comment: @jaume are you using the search engine ? the focus switches only for websites _other_ than your search engine. I see this behaviour too on 10.14.6, safari 12. Never noticed it before btw!

Comment: @anki Thank you for your comment, yes, I can reproduce the issue: the search field is in focus after doing a search. I've upvoted the question :-)

Comment: Strangely enough this works as desired with Safari on iPadOS.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same answer that you are looking for, and I know that this answer is not the exact solution you were looking for, but it may ease the frustration a bit until a better solution is found.

I remapped my `Caps Lock` key to function as the `Esc` key, so after I do a search from the address bar, hitting `Esc` is a quick and ergonomic keypress away that lets me keep my fingers on the home row.

If you're extra fancy and like to remap `Caps Lock` to `Control`, there's a solution to that as well. Using the free app called [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org), you can remap the `Caps Lock` key to both `Control`, if held and another key is pressed, and also `Esc`, if pressed by itself.

If using Karabiner Elements, and you need `Caps Lock` functionality, you can either assign it to the `Control` key or, what I do, is assign it to toggle when I press both left and right shift at the same time.

I hope someone else finds a true solution or that Apple updates Safari with at least an option to change this behavior.

Comment: Vim user here, so I do appreciate an easy ESC.